# Format to text file with predefined size for each field

Tags: excel, text, vba

I have an Excel file which I need to convert to text file. Now the thing is that for each value there is a specified field size which should be there in text file. For example:

if my Excel contains a character of size 10 with value `ABCDEF`, then in text file it should be as `ABCDEF____` (4 spaces).

After this next value is appended in similar manner with its rest of the size is left blank.

Any kind of hint or pointer will be really helpful on how to procede with this.

Comment: Character count... i have lots of rows that all needs to be appended after other with given character count reserved for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string is in A1, and its length isn't more than the 10 characters:

```
=A1&REPT(" ",10-LEN(A1))
```